# Using JavaScript variable while accessing a Jinja template value

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am using `python jinja2` to pass `json` into a `HTML` file. The `json` I pass is similar as below,

```
result = { "config":{ "firstTitle" : "Report" } }
```

In my `HTML` file I have a `javascript` function as follows which works as expected,

```
    function dispDetails()
    {
        //This works as expected
        //It print 'Report' in the console
        console.log('{{ config.firstTitle }}');
    }
```

But if my `javascript` function is modified as to include a `javascript variable` the code is throwing erros,

```
function dispDetails()
    {
        //Error thrown : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number
        titleStr = "firstTitle";
        console.log('\'{{ config.'+titleStr+' }}\'');
    }
```

I have tried various ways to get this working, not sure where I am going wrong and would need some guidance on the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jinja variables are ONLY set at render time and what you are trying to do is impossible.

This is pseudo code, but you could potentially declare a js variable with your jinja json and access that:

```
var config = {{ config | tojson }};
function dispDetails()
{
    titleStr = "firstTitle";
    console.log(config[titleStr]);
}
```

Comment: I tried the fix mentioned. `console.log(config.titleStr)` returned undefined, so i tried `console.log(config[titleStr])` which worked for me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @nidHi ah, of course! that would do it. my js is a little rusty. Updated my answer :)